# Proving a function is a regular immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Given is the function (which is a 3D-dim vector):

$ \phi(u, v) = (2\cos(u) +v\sin(u/2)\cos(u), 2\sin(u) + v\sin(u/2)\sin(u), v\cos(u/2))$

with $u \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $v \in (-1,1)$

To prove is that $\phi$ is a regular immersion.

The textbook I have only has definition and doesn't contain much methodology on how to do such proofs.

I found a few similar questions on the site, where they solved it by showing that the determinate of the Jacobian is different than 0, but I have a 3-Dim with 2 variables here so I can't make a 3x3 matrix like in the other example ([Proving a function to be an immersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917914/proving-a-function-to-be-an-immersion)).

Lastly it's says that the image of $\phi$ is a Möbius band.

The exercise is 1.4 from J.Olver's Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations.

Edit: I found in another book, that it is possible to perform two simple coordinate transformations to create two neighborhoods $W_1$ and $W_2$ that can cover the Möbius strip. With that we can show that it's a regular surface.

I assume since part of the definition of a regular manifold is it being able to be written as the union of two disjoint sets, this satisfies the requirement and therefore it's proven, correct?

The transformations are for

$W_1$: $u' = u - \pi/2$ and $ v' = v$.

$W_2$: $u' = u + 3\pi/2$ and $ v' = -v$

I don't understand the reasoning for choosing the transform $v$ like this. But generally the solution makes sense.

Comment: Re: your original question: To show $\phi$ is an immersion, it's enough to show the vector-valued partial derivatives $\phi_{u}$ and $\phi_{v}$ are linearly independent (e.g., have non-vanishing cross product) at each point of the domain.

Comment: Impressive, very nice.